# Can't build an app for distribution after joining existing enterprise developer program

Tags: ios, xcode7, provisioning-profile, enterprise

I joined an existing **enterprise developer program**. I was able to run the app in developer mode, but had issues with building and archiving. The certificate for creating a **universal distribution** app is already present, but I am not able to build with it. How can I do it in steps??

Comment: What error did you get?

Comment: No codesigning identities (i.e. certificate and private key pairs) that match the provisioning profile specified in your build settings (“example App Profile”) were found.

Xcode can attempt to fix this issue. This will reset your code signing and provisioning settings to recommended values and resolve issues with signing identities and provisioning profiles.

Comment: Does it has a button "Fix issue"? what happen if you click that button?

Comment: Yes it has but its building for developer again. I want to build with existing certificate. Do I need any identity, but i read that for enterprise we dont need identity.

Comment: http://www.flipcreator.net/icreateapp/create-distribution-certificate.html

Comment: This is for creating new certificate. But I already have an existing one. How can I use it.

Comment: Did you download it? Just double click on it.

Comment: You can add your accout to Xcode: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppStoreDistributionTutorial/AddingYourAccounttoXcode/AddingYourAccounttoXcode.html

Comment: I think being the team member you only have the right to develop not distribute.

Comment: @anhtu : I have added the account before and able to see all the certificates in view details.

Comment: @Zubair : Do I have to ask for the distribution identity from the admin?

Comment: @Aslam what account did you add? `enterprise developer program` or just a normal developer account?

Comment: enterprise developer program

Answer (score 1):

The certificate is only half the necessary parts.  You also need the key for the certificate.

Open `Keychain Access` on your Mac and select the Certificates filter on the left.  When you select the certificate for your Enterprise Distribution, make sure you there is a green check mark in the top section next to a message that says "This certificate is valid" (bubble 4 in picture below).

Also, and this is likely your problem, you need to make sure there is a triangle next to the certificate that allows you to expand it (See bubble 3 in picture below).  Without that, you have no way to code sign using the distribution certificate.  You will need to get the private key from the person who created the certificate, or get the key off of the machine that was used to generate the certificate signing request file (CSR) used to generate the cert.

[image]

Comment: I am not able to add the certificate its showing "The contents of this item cannot be retrieved".

Comment: Are you trying to import the p12 file (for the key) to your keychain?  If so, try this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18319568/3708242